# Gigabyte GA-A55m NO POST

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, post

Just put together a new computer with some basic parts from newegg.  I am getting no video, and no post at all.  Nothing from the speaker.  The speaker definitely works as I have pulled the memory and found it beeps.  Tested with 2 known working memory sticks, one after the other.  Tested from VGA and DVI from motherboard, as well as a known working graphics card.  Everything seems to turn on, both Hard Drive and internal CD drive operate.  Next step is test with different PSU, any suggestions?

I found this post: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/308591-30-a55m-post

He seems to have the same problem, but does not mention that he solved it, only that he RMA'ed this board multiple times.

Thank you!

```
Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-A55M-DS2
CPU: AMD A4-3300 2.5G
Memory: 4 gig G Skill F3-10666CL9S
HDD: Seagate 500 gigs
PSU: Rosewell 350W
```

Comment: Have to ask the stupid questions first to get them out of the way... have you checked the power supply input voltage selector?  It's possible it may be set to 240vac instead of 120vac? This gives 6v to the cpu (it NEEDs 12vdc) making the cpu not fire over, while the regulated 5v will power the drives, cd-roms, everything else. (Ask me how I know this!) Of personal note, DO NOT switch the input to 120vac if your mains power is 240vac, as suddenly your CPU vanishes in a glorious puff of magic smoke since you just supplied it with 24vdc.  Eeek!!  But the 5v rail works great!  (don't do this!)

Comment: Thats definitely a great stupid question :D Yes just double checked it, it is currently set to 115.  Just attempted boot with a different psu and nothing.  Disconnected everything but the motherboard and cpu. Ill do a couple more tests.  Also I double checked the monitor and it is fine, thought I should mention that, Thanks!

Comment: Another thought... did you check the cmos battery/clear jumper?  Most boards are shipped with it in 'clear' to prevent battery drain... and in the clear position, it won't boot.  And starting with just power supply and motherboard is an excellent start.  Get it to boot, then add something else, do it again.  Repeat until all hooked up or failure found.

Comment: Gotcha, just double checked, actually didn't have any jumper.  Looks like its a 2 pin clear CMOS though.

Comment: 20-pin power connector from PSU or 24-pin?  Also, is there a separate 4-pin squarish yellow/black power connector going to m/b near cpu?  my amd m/b had a 24-pin connector, AND the extra 4-pin.  I'm shotgunning here, you're welcome to tell me to hush.  IDE flat cables can stop boot if hooked up reversed (uh, rotated, not flipped, but try all 4 configs)  If didn't fire over with other PSU, it's definitely something with the m/b.

Comment: Gotcha, Thanks for the assistance!  Just gonna RMA it.  Bummer, ironically this is the first time I've gone with a AMD socket, guess I'll stick with Intel! O.o

Comment: Alittle update.  Upon removing the heatsink from the CPU I found it GLUED to the heatsink.  It was not because it became fused from heat, but the AMD Factory supplied thermal paste is INCREDIBLY sticky.  I put my finger on the heatsink where some thermal paste is and am able to actually pick the heatsink up.  Pretty horrible quality stuff.  RMA'ing the lot.